# Descomponer un numero en unos con problema en el despliegue

Tags: java

He realizado un programa en java, el cual descompone en una suma de numeros unos, a un valor x, el cual es ingresado por el usuario. El inconveniente que poseo se presenta cuando despliego, ya que siempre tengo un signo "+" extra, ejemplo:
establesco que el limite sea 5.

> 1
>
> 1+1+
>
> 1+1+1+
>
> 1+1+1+1+
>
> 1+1+1+1+1+

y obtengo esta respuesta.
¿Comó podria hacer, para remover aquel signo extra tan molesto?(he intentado de varias maneras, pero no he consegido llegar al resultado deseado)

código:

```
    String coma ="+";
    String serie="";
    int unos=1;
    int li=0;
    int cont=0;
    String u="1";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese limite para la generación de laa sucesión");
    li= sc.nextInt();
    int other;
    int other2;
    other=li;
    other2=li;
    other2=other2-1;
    int te=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=li; i++)
    {

        for(int j=0; j<(other-other2); j++)
        {
            if(i>1)
            {
                serie= u+coma;
                System.out.print(serie);

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(u);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("");
        other2--;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de que el form imprima los unos deberias imprimir el primer uno, y dentro del `for` imprimes solo los faltantes anteponiendo primero el signo más `(+)`. ejemplo para 5

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int limite = 5;
  for(int i = 0; i < limite; i++){
    System.out.print("1");
    for(int avance = 0; avance < i; avance++){
      System.out.print("+1");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

La salida de este programa es

```
1
1+1
1+1+1
1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1
```

Comment: Lo siento, no exprese muy bien el ejemplo, ya lo edite, disculpa, y no, no es la solución...

Comment: Hice una modificación a la respuesta, espero le sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Modificando el `if` con una condición compuesta para que imprima `serie` hasta el limite menos 1.

```
if(i>1 && j<(other-other2)-1) {
  serie = u+coma;
  System.out.print(serie);
} else {
  System.out.print(u);
}
```

Por cierto, resulta algo confuso lo de las variables `other` y `other2`